# How to change the color of edit text line?

Tags: android

How to change the color of edit text line?[image]

I have no idea how to change it,will i have to do it with the style element ?

Comment: Could you use something like the android asset studio holo theme generator? http://android-holo-colors.com/

Comment: You can make your own background  by following this tutorial : 
http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/changing-background-color-and-border-color-of-an-edittext-widget-using-state-list-in-android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to change the color of edit text line?

That is part of the `EditText` background. As daentech suggests, using [the Android Holo Colors generator](http://android-holo-colors.com/) can simplify setting up the style with your desired color.

The generator will define an `<item name="android:editTextBackground">@drawable/apptheme_edit_text_holo_dark</item>` element that overrides the default `EditText` background. That points to a `StateListDrawable` resource (`<selector>`), which in turn points to a series of nine-patch PNG files with the proper color.

Comment: can't i do i it manually ?with some color value ? does holo colors genearator use images?

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava: "with some color value ?" -- no, because `EditText` has different looks for different states, and because the `EditText` background consists of nine-patch PNG files. "does holo colors genearator use images?" -- yes, as I mentioned in my answer ("which in turn points to a series of nine-patch PNG files with the proper color").